# Need to convert code from c# to java

Tags: java, c#, select, foreach, var

I never learnt C#.
Here I got in C# & I need to use this method into java.

I tried with different combination & permutation. But I didn't get success into this.

```
String word = "#############";
foreach(var c in from ch in word
                where ch >= 'B' &&
                        ch <= 'F' &&
                        sleng < 4
                select ch)
```

Can anybody I have idea how to covert above code into java?

Comment: Hint: A where clause in a Linq query can be turned into an `if` statement within the `foreach`.

Comment: Why don't you learn c# before this task

Comment: Your code is not a method. This is not only C# bound. Give it name, return type and let it take the string as input, then you will be able to use it as method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done it .Main start need to convert into **toCharArray()**
And it's not possible to use query as c# into java. 
You need to use if else statement for this.

```
    for (char ch : word.toCharArray()) {

            if (ch >= 'B' && ch <= 'F' && soundexString.length() < 4) {

                ... ...
...
            }
        }
```